# How can I extend FB's built-in open graph action type, watch?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, object-type

I want to use open graph to "watch real time sports matches."
Built-in watch action-type  seems to support only TV-show, movie, and video and doesn't support game match.

Could anyone tell me how to extend built-in watch action-type?
And if possible, please show me how to extend built-in object-types?

Built-in game match object type requires sores and players.
But you can not know the box scores untile the game ending, actually.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking here, are you asking can the built-in action types work with objects it's not documented as being compatible with? if so, no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Graph doesn't support extending actions today -- instead, try creating a custom watch action and game (or match) object.

Comment: Thank you! But it seems that Submissions for a custom Watch action will no longer be accepted.